# How to Add icons to folders and files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to develop android file explorer application. I get both file name and file path into two separate ArrayLists and then assign to ArrayAdapter. I used TextView to display file names and folder names.  File explorer is working well. Now I need to add folder icon to a folders and file icon to files.

It is not possible to do in layout file because all folders and files are in same ArrayAdapter. I tried to do it in code, but I have to give whole ArrayList to ArrayAdapter as a parameter, hence I cannot categories files and folders separately.

I will be appropriate if anyone have any suggestion to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solving the same problem.

1. Extend your list row with some `ImageView` where you will set the icon. Example 
   file_row.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@android:id/text1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Fill `ArrayAdapter` with items like `File` or something from which information `isDirectory()` and `getFileName()` can be obtained.
3. (optional) Sort the adapter items with comparator comparing them to left dirs on top. Method `Adapter.sort(Comparator)`
4. In your `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method in ArrayAdapter do something like this.

   ```
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
           if(convertView == null)
           {
               convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.file_row, null);
           }

           FileItem item = getItem(position);

           TextView nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
           nameTextView.setText(item.getFileName());

           ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

           if (item.isDirectory())
           {
               imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.directory);
           }
           else
           {
               imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file);
           }

           return convertView;
       }
   ```

Of course you can do some more sophisticated stuff like setting different icon for each file type, setting thumbnails etc. But the principle will be similar.

Comment: Still I have a problem. Here in the layout I used only a TextView. Then I gave that layout to the ArrayAdapter as a parameter. After that I set it into ListAdapter. So as you said how to add ImageView to the layout?